# Inserting variable inside regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use variable inside the below regex but I am unable to get the correct output.

```
   (?<=="Page 2" class="fl" href=")(.*?)(?=\"><span class=\"csb)
```

--
I tried below but not sure I missed something.

```
(("?<== \"Page "+ pages++ + "\" class=\"fl\" href=\"")"(.*?)"(?=\"><span class=\"csb"));
```

--

How I can achieve it?

Edit:

```
   aria-label="Page 2" class="fl" href="/search?q=.net+regex+tester&amp;ei=p3Q7XNzkBt6RwgPrga-YBQ&amp;start=10&amp;sa=N&amp;ved=0ahUKEwic1OvFo-vfAhXeiHAKHevAC1MQ8tMDCHw"><span class="csb ch"
```

--
Added the source.

Comment: One pair of parentheses should be inside the string at the beginning and at the end. Also, you should be using the [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) for HTML parsing. Regex is not difficult and error prone (e.g. if attributes are inverted).

Comment: It's generally considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4415734) to use RegEx to parse a structured language such as HTML as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to view on this issue not like "how to write correct regex query".

Just look like whole c# regex variable (object).

Your code in c# looks like (added double quotes)

```
var reg = new Regex(@"(?<==""Page 2"" class=""fl"" href="")(.*?)(?=\""><span class=\""csb)");
```

So, we need to String.Format the Regex string query, like

```
var reg = new Regex($@"(?<==""Page {page}"" class=""fl"" href="")(.*?)(?=\""><span class=\""csb)");
```

Btw, if we are talking about parsing html, it's strongly not recommended to use Regular Expression. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2114398)

Comment: @nav, use HtmlAgilityPack for parsing or at least XmlDocument class

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions I will look into HtmlAgilityPack.